# renaming current module

Tags: haskell, module

Is it possible to rename current module ?
Let's say I want to introduce data constructors Left and Right, but these would clash with Prelude.Left and Right. I don't want to write everywhere MyModule.Left and MyModule.Right, I would prefer to rename it somehow to MyModule as M and write M.Left. Is it possible ? What are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 4):

Dario's answer gives the easiest way to do this, but since you ask for alternatives as well, you might want to look at [the description of `import` declarations](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html#sect5.3) in the Haskell report, or at [the "Loading modules" section](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) of Learn You a Haskell.

One common alternative to local aliases (i.e. `import qualified SomeModule as X`) is just to hide the `Prelude` functions (or constructors) if you know you'll not need them:

```
import Prelude hiding (Left, Right)
import MyModule
```

You can also import different parts of a module in different ways: one common trick is to import a module's types directly but alias its functions:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

simpleMap :: Map String Int
simpleMap = M.singleton "one" 1

simpleSet :: Set String
simpleSet = S.singleton "one"
```

This allows us to use both `singleton` functions, but we also don't have to type `M.Map` and `S.Set` in every type signature.

Answer (score 1):

```
import qualified YourModule as M
```

Comment: My own Left and Right are defined in MyModule, and I want to use them there.

Answer (score 0):

You just have one module. In this case, it's the very simplest solution to just hide the data-constructors (Left, Right) from the Prelude (These are defined there):

```
module MyModule where

import Prelude hiding (Left,Right)
```

Alternativly, you can simply import the Prelude qualified. Then you have to stick some letter before any Prelude functions / stuff / etc:

```
module MyModule where

import qualified Prelude as P
```